# Read Network Requests and Response Headers - Chrome Extension V3

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I can’t seem to figure out how to read, but not modify, the outgoing network requests and response **headers** for a chrome extension in manifest v3. From my experimentation, `declarativeNetRequest` and the rule definitions are primarily geared around **modifying** the request / response header, but all I want to do is to read the request URL and the response headers. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I’m looking to avoid having the `debugger` permission enabled and not using the `chrome.debugger` to do this.

Comment: Same as in MV2: use chrome.webRequest, just don't add `'blocking'`.

Answer (score 2):

declarativeNetRequests is not the right chrome API for collecting request/response headers. You need to add a permission for `webRequest`. Here is how you get them in background.js with web

```
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(async function(details) {
    // get response headers here here
}, {urls: ['<all_urls>']}, ['responseHeaders'])

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function(details) {
    // get request headers here
}, {urls: ['<all_urls>']}, ['requestHeaders'])
```